# M2 - Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34

Tags: magento2

I downgraded magento to 2.4.2, now I get this error if I open the website:

**Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You faced this issue because you are using PHP 8, Magento 2.4.2 does not support PHP 8 yet.

If you would like to continue with Magento 2.4.2, you have to switch PHP to version 7.

Comment: You are right! I changed to PHP Version 7.4.23 and now it works. thx!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!