# Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, php-7, magento2.4.5

As per the Adobe Magento 2 Official documentation.
[System requirements](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html) for Magento 2.4.5 is PHP 8.1 
I am getting following error. 
**Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass()** 
Most of the solutions on internet suggest installation of PHP 7.4
but then PHP 7.4 doesn't match with official requirements.
Can I get some expert advice/solution on this issue.

Comment: Please post a complete error message with a trace for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PHP 8.1 for Magento 2.4.5

There are some suggestions that say that using PHP 7 (or 7.4) is for the upgrade process, once you upgrade your site to Magento 2.4.5, you have to switch to PHP 8.1

Related question:
[M2 - Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360850/m2-deprecated-functionality-method-reflectionparametergetclass-is-depreca)

Answer (score 0):

Base on the PHP8.0 you can replace that function by getType()

```
Use ReflectionParameter::getType() and the ReflectionType APIs should be used instead
```

Check the PHP document: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php